# Are there 4 position switches that control power to a circuit and provide state?

Tags: arduino, switches

I'm trying to find a 4 position switch to use with an arduino project.

The first position would be off, as in no power to the arduino.  Positions 2,3,4 would all provide power to the arduino and I need to be able to tell which position the switch is in.  Think of

OFF-LOW-MED-HIGH

What sort of switch would accomplish this, and how would I wire the power and the pins to the digital pins on the arduino?

Comment: Rotary or slide or perhaps radio button switches come to mind but you have to make a decision as to what you want it to look and work like. If not a physical switch, up-down buttons or an encoder with LEDs and (optionally) EEPROM storage- lots of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DP4T (dual-pole, quadruple-throw) slide switch, like this one: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SS-24E06-TG%205%20(P)/CKN10394-ND/2747191[image: Slide Switch]
Since the two sides are independent, you can use one of them for power and the other for the signal to your Arduino.

On the power side, you'd wire the common (middle terminal) of the switch to the Vcc of the Arduino and three of the four other terminals to the power supply.

On the signal side, you'd wire the common to ground and the other terminals to inputs of the Arduino. (Don't forget pull-up resistors.)

The switch I linked to has the nice feature that it is make-before-break (MBB), according to the Digi-Key listing, so the Arduino won't lose power while the switch is being slid. If you actually have three separate power supplies, you don't want this, as two of the supplies will be briefly shorted together when you slide the switch. Instead, use a break-before-make (BBM) switch, and add a capacitor large enough to power the Arduino for the few milliseconds while the switch is sliding.

Comment: A MBB format may sound good to prevent a power loss, however note that adjacent power inputs will actually be shorted together momentarily when sliding the switch. This may not be ideal for some supplies.

Comment: My understanding of the question was not that there were multiple power supplies, just one, and that it should be connected to the Arduino for any of the three "on" positions. I'll edit my answer to discuss this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A 4 position 2 pole (2P4T) rotary switch may work best.  (Some multiple pole slide switches may require a more complex connection.)

One such rotary switch can be seen here on an ebay link: http://www.ebay.com/itm/8Pcs-6mm-Knurled-Shaft-10Pin-Rotary-Switch-Potentiometer-2-Pole-4-Position-2P4T-/231228428440
There are similar switches in many shapes and sizes, just remember the 2P4T type.
 (It may also be listed as a DP4T.)

As you can see on a close up view there are two pins that are closer to the bottom center, these would be the common pins.  One of these common pins would go to your Arduino power input, then the nearest 4 other pins would be your power inputs (off, low, medium, high). As you rotate the switch each of the 4 input pins will be connected to the common pin.

If you want a digital position indication you would use the other half of the switch (the other pole) with the common pin grounded and the other pins going to the Arduino digital inputs.  Since the second pole section of the switch follows the first your Arduino digital inputs can detect a low on one of the pins and determine the position of the switch. Note that you would only really need to connect 3 of the outer pins since in the off position nothing is working.

The digital inputs to Arduino can be selected as needed, just remember that when coding you need to enable a pull-up on the input pin to read an incoming low signal.

See the schematic representation below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faZN5S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Note that many rotary switches have user-settable stops to limit rotation - it may be easier to find a 2P6T switch, and set the stop to only permit four positions.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post my final solution.  I bought these DP4T, 4 position [slide switches](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/c-k-components/SS-24E06-TG%205%20(P)/CKN10394-ND/2747191) from DigiKey.  There are two sides, which I will call the **A** and **B** side.

For both sides, pin 3 is the common pin.  Take a look at side **A** below.  Power comes into pin 3, and 2, 4, 5 are all shorted together (soldered, and underneath the shrink wrap, with a single wire coming out.  So position 1, which has no connection won't provide any power.  Positions 2, 3, 4 all connect pins 2, 4, 5 with the common pin and thus provides power.  This switch is designed to that there is no loss of power when moving from 2-3, 3-4, etc.

[image: Side A - Power]

Now let's look at side **B** which provides the various states, which I will call **Low**, **Med**, and **High**. This is pretty simple.  Pins 2-5 each have a colored wire soldered to it.  Pin 1 doesn't, because that is the **Off** state, but theoretically you could use that for a fourth state.  I'm using this in an arduino, so pin 3, which is the common pin goes to **ground** and pins 2, 4, 5 each go to a digital input pin on the arduino, e.g 10, 11, 12.  When the switch is in position 2, ground is connected to pin 10 on the arduino and I will be able to read a **HIGH** state.  Pins 11 and 12 aren't connected to ground so they will read a **LOW** state.  Moving the slide to positions 3 and 4 will produce a similar result for pins 11 and 12.

[image: Side B - State]